# how to get access RelativeLayout as a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I can't figure out how to access my RelativeLayout programmatically so that I could call a method such as `relativeLayout.getChildCount();` inside a Handler.

Edit - alright, if I wanted to get the total number of Views in my RelativeLayout, what function would I call?

Comment: Please make clear your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615723/getting-child-elements-from-linearlayout

Comment: Yes but the problem here is I'd like to get the number of Views defined in my XML relative layout, how do I link that to a java form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In folder res/layout, I assume your layout named layout.xml

1. make sure your RelativeLayout have android:id segment

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout" > //the id name can be acsessed in activity

           <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. access that RelativeLayout id in activity

   ```
   public class mainActivity extends Activity {
       //make variable globally
       RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout;


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           //the layout file
           setContentView(R.layout.layout);

           //access the RelativeLayout and initialiszed the object
           myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
           myRelativeLayout.getChildCount();

       }
   }
   ```