# Synchronize scrolling on multiple RecyclerViews in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, synchronization, horizontal-scrolling

I want to implement an horizontal *RecyclerView* inside a vertical *RecyclerView*.

The end result should be like this:

[image]

So, for each element in the vertical *RecyclerView*, I need another one in an horizontal way. Kind of like a school schedule, with the Day in the left, and the actual schedule on the right, scroll-able horizontally.

I managed to achieve this, by putting an *RecyclerView* inside of the first *RecyclerView* item. Everything works perfectly, but all the horizontal *RecyclerView*s are scrolling separately. What I want to do is make all the horizontal *RecyclerView*s to sync and scroll at the same time. How can I achieve this?

The way I set the adapter and the horizontal *RecyclerView* inside the **onBindViewHolder** method of the vertical adapter is this:

```
scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(context, data);
holder.scheduleRecyclerView.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
holder.scheduleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Answer (score 6):

Each recyclerview should add the below `scroll listener`.

`m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager` is the parent RecyclerView whose items has a recyclerview.

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            scrollAllRecyclerView(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        private void scrollAllRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                // Scroll children RecyclerViews except the recyclerView that is listened.
                for (int i = 0; i < m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    RecyclerView child = (RecyclerView) m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                    if (child != recyclerView) {
                        scroll(child, dx, dy);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void scroll(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
            recyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(this);
        }
```

**EDIT :** In your parent recyclerview adapter.

```
 @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(mContext);
            .. set layout manager & your adapter .

            if (scrollListener != null) {
                recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener );
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener );
            }
            return new RecyclerViewViewHolder(recyclerView);
        }
```

**EDIT 2** : There is an [Table View library](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableViewSample) which scroll all child recyclerviews sync. 
You can check the source code

Comment: Where should I put this new scroll listener? In the parent RecyclerView adapter or in the fragment where I set the adapter for the parent RecyclerView? Also, how do I add the new scroll listener to the child adapters? Thanks

Comment: you should add this scroll listener in parent RecyclerView' onCreateViewHolder where you create a recyclerview for each item of parent one. I have editted my answer.

Comment: Okay, I moved the creation of the child RecyclerViews in onCreateViewHolder method. But here, how can I refer to the parent RecyclerView, the *m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager*?

Comment: I updated my code with your EDIT part, but still I don't know how to refer to the parent RecyclerView in it's own adapter.

Comment: I did it like this:
@Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }
But now I get *java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView* at this line *RecyclerView child = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);*
Any idea why?

Comment: You should create an custom recyclerview adapter which contains a set/get method to refer to it

Comment: I managed to refer to the parent *RecyclerView* as said above, but now I get that Class Cast Exception here *RecyclerView child = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);*. Both views are *RecyclerView* so I don't understand why.

Comment: try it mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i)

Comment: I did, still the same Error.

Comment: probably you are trying to get view from child recyclerview. You should do this from your horizontal recyclerview instead of vertical one.

Comment: Yes, but the way I implemented it, the vertical one scrolls all of them vertically, while the horizontal ones are the one in light gray, which scroll individually. Maybe you didn't quite understand the implementation. I only want to synchronize the horizontal ones, when scrolling one of them

Comment: I know why I get the ClassCastException. In my vertical RecyclerView I have a linear layout with an imageView and a RecyclerView. How can I refer only to the RecyclerView, because with m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager .getChildAt() it will return all the View, not only the RecyclerView.

Comment: it is very simple. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6615754/4606266

Comment: Thanks, I manage to do that, but I can only do it by referring to the layout from findViewById. How can I make this reference as a child from the parent m_jParentRecyclerViewLayoutManager?

Comment: Okay. I finally managed to do it. The problem though is when I scroll, the scroll goes at the end of the queue and it freezes the application.
I'm going to up your answer for the effort. Thank you

Comment: I managed to implement your solution with some changes, but the core part is the same. The only issue i'm having i that if while one recyclerview is SETTLING after a fast DRAG, i click on another recyclerview, the first one will carry on with it's scrolling and the whole thing goes out of sync..

Comment: @dvdciri any solution for the problem stated by you?

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity have recyclerView vertical:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        verticalRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val onScrollListener = object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                (recyclerView.adapter as? Adapter)?.matchOffset()
            }
        }

        verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
        verticalRecyclerView.adapter = Adapter(verticalRecyclerView)
    }
}
```

In Adapter have list recyclerView horizontal:

```
class Adapter(private val parentRV: RecyclerView): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    var horizontalRecyclerViews = mutableListOf<RecyclerView>()
    var absoluteOffset: Int? = null
    //numberOfItems
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 25
    }

    fun matchOffset(offset: Int? = absoluteOffset) {
        offset?.let { offsetValue ->
            horizontalRecyclerViews.forEach { recyclerView ->
                val currentOffset = recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()
                if (offsetValue != currentOffset) {
                    recyclerView.scrollBy(offsetValue-currentOffset, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false)
        return  CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.view.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

        val onTouchListener = object: RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
            override fun onTouchEvent(p0: RecyclerView, p1: MotionEvent) {
            }
            override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(p0: RecyclerView, p1: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                if (p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    absoluteOffset = p0.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
            override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(p0: Boolean) {
            }
        }

        val onScrollListener = object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val value = recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()
                matchOffset(value)
            }
        }


        val child = BlockAdapter()
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.tag = position
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners()
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(onTouchListener)
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
        holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView.adapter = child
        horizontalRecyclerViews.add(holder.view.horizontalRecyclerView)
    }
}

class BlockAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    //numberOfItems
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 30
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_block, parent, false)
        return  CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.block.setBackgroundColor(
                if (position % 2 == 0) {
                    Color.BLUE
                } else {
                    Color.RED
                }
        )
        holder.view.block.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        holder.view.block.text = position.toString()
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    init {
    }

}
```