# Sync scrolling of multiple horizontal recyclerview inside vertical one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a vertical RecyclerView, where each row is a horizontal RecyclerView.
What I want to do is that no matter which horizontal RecyclerViews you scroll, all of the others will scroll together.

Here is my code:

Vertical Recyclerview:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/purchase_ticket_seats_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/view_seats_horizontal"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

View inside Vertical Recyclerview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    >


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/seats_horizontal_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/view_seat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/seat_row_name" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seat_row_name"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried putting vertical recyclerview inside horizontal scroll view and disabled horizontal scroll of horizontal recyclerview. But no luck. I also tried giving the same scroll listener for horizontal recyclerview.

Here is the image that I want to achieve. The user can scroll vertically and if user scrolls one horizontal row others scroll together:

[image]

Comment: You can reference the my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358290/13920894](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358290/13920894)